# Selecting pandas rows between list of datetime ranges

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe, df:

```
                     event
time
2013-10-09 06:27:00   breakfast
2013-10-09 07:25:00      school
2013-10-09 10:25:00        exam
2013-10-09 12:00:00       lunch
2013-10-09 12:00:00    homework
2013-10-09 19:20:00      dinner
2013-10-09 23:25:00       sleep
```

I also have two list of times of the same size:

```
lower = array(['2013-10-09T06:15:00.000000000', 
               '2013-10-09T07:00:00.000000000',
               '2013-10-19T13:00:00.000000000',  dtype='datetime64[ns]')

upper = array(['2013-10-09T11:15:00.000000000', 
               '2013-10-09T12:00:00.000000000',
               '2013-10-09T17:00:00.000000000', dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Is there a non-iterative panda-esque way that could let me get the rows in df bounded by
[upper[0],lower[0]], [upper[1],lower[1]], [upper[2],lower[2]], ... such that we get

```
                     event
time
2013-10-09 06:27:00   breakfast
2013-10-09 07:25:00      school
2013-10-09 10:25:00        exam
2013-10-09 07:25:00      school
2013-10-09 10:25:00        exam
2013-10-09 12:00:00       lunch
```

as an output?

Comment: Added the dataframe!

Comment: pls post your expected output

Comment: added expected output

Comment: `2013-10-09 06:27:00` this is not your upper[1] then why this is present as first row in your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very panda-esque (but probably not memory-efficient):

```
(
    events.assign(key=1)
    .merge(pd.DataFrame({"lower": lower, "upper": upper, "key": 1}), on="key")
    [lambda df: df.time.between(d.lower, d.upper)]
    [["time", "event"]]
    .drop_duplicates()
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Would events be the event series in df?

Comment: I think `events` should be `df.reset_index()` from the code in your answer

Answer (score 0):

not a pandas function, maybe stil what you want?

```
[[u,l] for u, l in zip(upper, lower)]
```